# Button on click save objects to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have an event that is when you click a button I want to send an `int`, `string`, `datetime` and `bool` to my database.
Right now it will get the input from my webform for the "Company" and the "DayNumber". I want to get the value of my `CheckBox01` as the boolean for WeatherRain and the input from the Date. You should be able to choose the date not just take it from "now".
I don't know what would be the best way to get this done, I do have around 100 different fields to get user input from.

```
protected void btnTryck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dagbok bok = DagbokFactory.CreateNew();

    bok.Company = String.Format(TextBox1.Text);
    bok.DayNumber = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox19.Text);
    bok.WeatherRain = false;
    bok.Date = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Do you have 100 input field on your page??

Comment: Yes unfortunately I do have 100 input fields, it is a client that want their "daily diary" for building contractors as a web form instead of in paper form. It will be horrible to work with since over 50 of them are mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the boolean from your `CheckBox01` use its [Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked.aspx) property.

```
bok.WeatherRain = CheckBox01.Checked;
```

As for the date problem, I'd suggest using a `DateTimePicker` control to let the user select the date and get its value with the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

Use Checkbox's checked property for this as shown below:

```
protected void btnTryck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dagbok bok = DagbokFactory.CreateNew();

    bok.Company = String.Format(TextBox1.Text);
    bok.DayNumber = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox19.Text);
    bok.WeatherRain = CheckBox01.Checked;
    bok.Date = DateTime.Now;
}
```